# SQL find and replace with wildcard

Tags: mysql, sql, replace

Starting position: I have a SQL-DB, that contains several tables with hunderts or tousends of entries. Now in several fields (columns) there are URLs, that should be shortened (to a extract of the original URL) and added a new parameter. The thing is, that there is some «find & replace» to do:

1. Find all (OLD) URLs inside all Fields/Columns of all Tables (stand-alone or inbetween text)…

   http://www.domain.com/click?p(abcdef)a(123456)url(http://www.url.com)
2. … and replace the old URL with the (NEW) URL:

   http://www.url.com/?at=uvwxyz

… as you can see I need a wildcard inside the url-parameter … like `http://www.domain.com/click?p(abcdef)a(123456)url(*)` because the old url ends with a `)` and I just need an extract of the old url (the second url) plus a new url-parameter.

- The url inside the ( and ) in the OLD url can vary … there are maybe hunderts or tousands of different urls.
- The URLs are in several fields in several tables … inside and mostly surrounded by text and not necessarily stand-alone (see table below).
- There could be *more than one* field/columns per entry with *none, one or more than one* URLs per field/column that should be changed.

Table Example:

```
+----------+---+-------------------+---------------+---+--------------+--------------+
| entry_id | … | field_id_1        | field_ft_1    | … | field_id_199 | field_ft_199 |
+----------+---+-------------------+---------------+---+--------------+--------------+
| 21364    | … | blabla URL blabla | NULL          | … | none         | none         |
| 21363    | … | text URL text     | text URL text | … | none         | URL          |
| …        | … | text URL text URL | NULL          | … | URL text     | none         |
+----------+---+-------------------+---------------+---+--------------+--------------+
```

Field/Column Value Example:

```
The new «App of the Week» is named «<a href="http://www.domain.com/click?p(abcdef)a(123456)url(https://itunes.apple.com/ch/app/popagraph/id587595362?mt=8)">PopAGraph</a>».
This App does this and that and bla bla bla <a href="http://www.domain.com/click?p(abcdef)a(123456)url(https://itunes.apple.com/ch/app/popagraph/id587595362?mt=8)">kostenlos</a>.
In the iOS Store there are «Editors Choise» like: «<a href="http://www.domain.com/click?p(abcdef)a(123456)url(https://itunes.apple.com/ch/app/the-room-two/id667362389?mt=8)">The Room Two</a>» (CHF 3.00). And some more Text bla bla bla.
```

**Update:** rewrote the whole question because of lack of details

Comment: I've done this with a sproc in the past, I'll post it if i can find it when i get into work in the morning, if you don't have a better solution by then

Answer (score 0):

To find last `URL` portion of the old string, use `substring_index` and `substr` functions.

**Example**:

```
SET @old_value := 
         'http://www.domain.com/click?p(abcdef)a(123456)url(http://www.url.com)';
select @url := substr( @u := substring_index( @old_value, '(', -1 )
               from 1 
               for ( length( @u ) - 1 ) 
       ) as url
```

This will return

```
+--------------------+
| url                |
+--------------------+
| http://www.url.com |
+--------------------+
```

To update the record using the new `url` value, you have to use `concat` to append query parameters to the url.

**Example**:

```
update my_table 
    set url_col = concat( @url, '/?at=uvwxyz' )
where
    url_col = @old_value
    -- and  -- add more conditions if required
    -- ... ...
```

***Refer to***:

- [MySQL: SUBSTRING_INDEX( str, delim, count )](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_substring-index)

  - Returns the substring from string str before count occurrences of the
    delimiter delim. If count is positive, everything to the left of the
    final delimiter (counting from the left) is returned. If count is
    negative, everything to the right of the final delimiter (counting
    from the right) is returned. SUBSTRING_INDEX() performs a
    case-sensitive match when searching for delim.

Comment: see my update — the last url portion of the old string will vary … there are maybe hunderts or tousands of different urls … does then your solution still work? … and: is this pure sql? (to insert via form @ phpmysql?)

Comment: So long as the new url pattern `(http://www.url.com)` is at tail end, this is going to work.

Comment: Thank you @Ravinder. Since I'm no SQL-Expert: Can I just insert both code-snippets into the Form in phpmyadmin? (with the correct «my_table», of course)

Comment: To be more confident, before running an update, first get satisfied by running the `select ...substring_index(...` query on your fields and then go with `update ...`.

Comment: ah ok, but I can do both with the form in phpmysql?

Comment: Yes, you can do that using PHPMyAdmin.

Comment: thx @Ravinder … but MySQL-Error: «Unknown column 'url_col' in 'where clause»

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/49385/discussion-between-ravinder-and-albuvee)